# Why does some cake make your tongue thick, and how to prevent it?

Tags: cake

I'll be baking a cheese-ham cake shortly and I remember that sometimes it makes your tongue 'thick' (for lack of a better word).

The symptoms are the feeling that the tongue/mouth is covered with the cake, like it's sticking to the skin. I'm not sure how to describe it accurately. I've just eaten a commercial grade muffin like cake with the same effect. It makes the mouth dry, maybe.

So, is there information about which flours are more prone to produce this effect? Is this somehow related to the flour? Can it be the butter/grease? The oven temp or the undercooking or overcooking? Maybe a reaction of the leavening agent?

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

**Edit:**
Ham-Cheese Cake

- 150g Cheese (Gouda or Emmental)
- 200g Ham
- 2  Chives
- 100g Butter or Margarine
- 3  Eggs
- 100g Flour
- 1  Tablespoon baking powder
- Salt & Pepper

Cut the cheese, ham and chives.

Cream the butter and add the eggs one at a time. Sieve the flour together with the baking powder and the salt, and mix into the butter.

Add the ingredients to the batter and put in the oven at 180ºC for 30'

Comment: Could you describe a cheese-ham cake more fully?  I don't know what you're referring to.  Is it like a quiche?  A list of ingredients and brief description of the recipe would help clarify.

Comment: To make sure I understand- is this the phenomenon that my family refers to as a food "sucking the spit right out of your mouth?", most noted in the cookies we feed to very young children and use to aid digestion?

Comment: @AdeleC, that must be it.

Comment: @CareyGregory, I've added the recipe. As you can see, it's not like a quiche at all.

Comment: When you say 'thick', you don't mean swollen, do you?  Because that'd be a sign of an allergic reaction.

Comment: @Joe, no, it's more like AdeleC's comment.

Comment: To me it also sounds like the description provided by AdeleC, for what it's worth. Maybe we should focus on the two examples given, digestive cookies and baby/toddler cookies?

Comment: Adele's description sounds like astringency, but I wouldn't expect that recipe to be very astringent.

Answer (score 6):

Meat fat/suet does cause similar effect on tongue and some “acidics”(e.g.lemon, vinegar, wine)  helps to balance it. 
If that’s the situation this Q/A may give some ideas for the solution.

[Why do fatty foods go with sour ones?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12700/why-do-fatty-foods-go-with-sour-ones)

Comment: Some fats 'coat' the tongue because their melting point is higher than the temperature in the mouth. I don't think this is the case, as butter or margarine is used.

Comment: @BaffledCook - butter and margarine have very high melting points, only a few degrees below body temperature. What other fats are you comparing to? Most saturated fats have roughly the same melting points, and unsaturated fats are much lower (liquid at room temperature).

Answer (score 1):

It might be the baking powder that's in it. I don't recognize the 'thick' feeling you're describing, but I find stuff with baking powder in it tastes different. It's described as a [metallic taste](http://chowhound.chow.com/topics/421300) by some, becasue apparantly there's [aluminum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baking_powder) in some brands.

Comment: I usually use Royal Baking Powder, I've looked at the ingredient list, and it doesn't state aluminum.

Comment: @BaffledCook If by "Royal Baking Powder" you mean [this brand](http://www.amazon.com/Royal-Baking-Powder-8-1-oz/dp/B0000GI3O4), aluminum is an ingredient: it includes "Sodium Aluminum Sulfate".

Comment: @TheodoreMurdock, I don't see Sodium Aluminum Sulfate in the ingredient list, even though it's the same brand.

Answer (score -1):

I think I know what you are talking about.  I worked in a grocery store bakery for a stint and I believe you are talking about what I would describe as "fur on your tongue". Makes you want to scrape it off.  I get it from the shortening based frosting and oily muffins from low cost commercial shortening fluff.  Have you had that experience from something home cooked?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have some reference material to check that?

Comment: Is this really an answer? Given that the recipe in question doesn't include shortening, I don't think you've really found the cause or a way of preventing it, as requested in the question.

Comment: @Jefromi, isn't shortening some sort of fat replacing butter?

Comment: @BaffledCook Yeah, it is, but since EDabM only noticed the effect in things that were mostly shortening, and didn't mention butter, I'm not entirely sure it's the same thing. In any case, there's nothing about what you might do about it, so...

Answer (score -1):

I've just made some gluten free rock cakes and used a table spoon of baker powder. And as usual it gives me a rough tongue. It last for over an hour before its normal again. It is definitely something to do with baking powder. Will need to find an alternative. 
I've been diagnosed with Coeliac disease for over 20 years

Answer (score -2):

This has baffled me too, for a long time. I just had a delicious muffin for lunch and now have the furry tongue. I get a similar effect from wine with a high level of tannin in it. A good cook told me it has something to do with the ratio of baking powder to flour. Since baking powder is a combo of creme of tartar and bicarbonate, it might be one or the other that is the culprit.

Again, not a good answer, but maybe it adds to the thinking.

Comment: "Adds to the thinking" is what comments are for. Answers should be (to the best of your knowledge) actual answers.

Answer (score -2):

I baked a banana cake last week and it had a bitter taste towards the end (when swallowing) and it was like sticking at the back of my mouth (giving me a feeling like I was about to choke). I read about cakes having a bitter taste and the reason was said to be too much baking soda than the required amount. I have not got the explanation of the sticky feeling but I suspect it could be the baking soda too.

Comment: This does not seem to be what the OP is describing.

Comment: I will give the answerer the benefit of the doubt and say that it could be the same problem - she describes "sticking at the back of my mouth", not just bitterness.